# how do I access nested JSON Objects from Newtonsoft.Json (C#)?

Tags: c#, json, winforms

Here is my JSON file that my C# WinForm application will need to access. Based on your account name (Windows AD Login), you will have access to specific files from the application.

Based on the suggestions of other developers, I was encouraged to use **Newtonsoft.Json**

My question is how do I get the values for the key "file"

```
[
  {
    "accountName": "admin.lastname",
    "files": [
      {
        "file": "department1.assistant.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department1.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department2.assistant.division.manager.1.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department2.assistant.division.manager.2.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department2.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department3.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department4.assistant.division.manager.1.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department4.assistant.division.manager.2.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department4.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department5.assistant.division.manager.1.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department5.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department6.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department7.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department8.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department9.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department10.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department11.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department12.assistant.division.manager.1.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department12.assistant.division.manager.2.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department12.assistant.division.manager.3.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department12.assistant.division.manager.4.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department12.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department13.js"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "accountName": "firstname.lastname",
    "files": [
      {
        "file": "department1.assistant.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department1.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department2.assistant.division.manager.1.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department2.assistant.division.manager.2.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department2.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department3.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department4.assistant.division.manager.1.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department4.assistant.division.manager.2.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department4.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department5.assistant.division.manager.1.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department5.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department6.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department7.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department8.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department9.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department10.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department11.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department12.assistant.division.manager.1.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department12.assistant.division.manager.2.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department12.assistant.division.manager.3.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department12.assistant.division.manager.4.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department12.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department13.js"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "accountName": "jason.bourne",
    "files": [
      {
        "file": "department1.assistant.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department1.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department2.assistant.division.manager.1.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department2.assistant.division.manager.2.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department2.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department3.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department4.assistant.division.manager.1.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department4.assistant.division.manager.2.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department4.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department5.assistant.division.manager.1.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department5.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department6.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department7.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department8.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department9.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department10.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department11.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department12.assistant.division.manager.1.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department12.assistant.division.manager.2.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department12.assistant.division.manager.3.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department12.assistant.division.manager.4.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department12.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department13.js"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "accountName": "admin.bourne",
    "files": [
      {
        "file": "department1.assistant.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department1.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department2.assistant.division.manager.1.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department2.assistant.division.manager.2.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department2.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department3.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department4.assistant.division.manager.1.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department4.assistant.division.manager.2.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department4.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department5.assistant.division.manager.1.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department5.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department6.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department7.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department8.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department9.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department10.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department11.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department12.assistant.division.manager.1.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department12.assistant.division.manager.2.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department12.assistant.division.manager.3.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department12.assistant.division.manager.4.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department12.division.manager.js"
      },
      {
        "file": "department13.js"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is my C# code and what I tried so far but I am stuck

```
    public void loadAccessControl(String fileName)
    {
        var locationInformation = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + fileName;
        using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(locationInformation))
        using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
        {
            JArray o = (JArray)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
            items = o;
            MessageBox.Show(items.ToString());
        }

        foreach (var item in items.Children())
        {
            var itemProperties = item.Children<JProperty>();
            var myElement = itemProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "accountName");
            var myElementValue = myElement.Value; ////This is a JValue type
            if (myElementValue.ToString().Contains(Environment.UserName))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Authorized");
                authorizedAccess = true;
                myElement = itemProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "files");
                myElementValue = myElement.Value; ////This is a JValue type
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

As I said before, I am new to using Newtonsoft's library so if there is a better way, please let me know.

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get from **Newtonsoft.Json** from **NuGet**.

Add class **File.cs**:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Accounts
{
    class File
    {
        [JsonProperty("file")]
        public string Filename { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Add class **Account.cs**:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Accounts
{
    class Account
    {
        [JsonProperty("accountName")]
        public string AccountName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("files")]
        public List<File> Files { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Add class **Program.cs**:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Accounts
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            const string filename = "accounts.json";
            List<Account> accounts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Account>>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename));

            foreach (Account account in accounts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(account.AccountName);
                foreach (File file in account.Files)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(file.Filename);
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of these options:

**Creating custom Models**

```
public class Account
{
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public List<FileItem> Files { get; set; }
}
public class FileItem
{
    public string File { get; set; }
}
```

And then use:

```
var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Account>>(jsonText);
```

**Without Creating Custom Models**

```
var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(jsonText)
    .Select(a => new
    {
        Account = a.Value<string>("accountName"),
        Files = a.Value<JArray>("files")
                    .Select(f => new { File = f.Value<string>("file") }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Also without `Newtonsoft.Json` you can use `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` and deserialize json value. `var result = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Account>>(txt);`

Answer (score 1):

Try the bellow code to deserialize object graph. then you can query the data easily

```
public class AccessControlFile
{
    public string file { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string accountName { get; set; }
    public List<AccessControlFile> files { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var jsonString = ""; // load from remote service or from a local file
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonString);

    }
}
```